# How can I protect the cell borders when hiding the table cells contents dynamically using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, cell

I am creating a table in plain JavaScript, and filling it up using onClick listener event in two ways - either clicking on a external button, or clicking on one of the cells itself; and in both ways, calling a function to randomly assign values to some of the cells. I am not able to hide the contents of my table cells using either of the methods available- display: none, and visibility: hidden. But I am still able to do it using fontSize = 0., wherin another problem crops-up viz the cells borders are lost. Thus my problem is that I want to hide my table cells contents whilst rendering values in them withput affecting the table structure.

I have already tried conventional methods available viz.

1) td {display: none;}, and  td {visibilty: hidden}

2) I have also tried inline CSS style method to hide the cell contents, but all these methods blank the table itself i.e. oblivate the cell borders themselves.

3) When I use:
document.getElementById('myelement').getElementsByTagName('td')[n[i]].style.fontSize = 0; I am able to hide the contents, but then cell borders are lost.

```
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <table id="myelement">
                <tr>
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                 ...  ....  ...
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
<script>
   ...
   for(let i=0;i<mycount;i++){
      td[n[i]].firstChild.nodeValue='X';
       document.getElementById('myelement').getElementsByTagName('td') 
       [n[i]].style.fontSize = 0;
     }
    ...
</script>
```

All the techniques available blank the table itself i.e. oblivate the cell borders themselves. The expected result is intact table structure when hiding the cells contents.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
Cell with `class="hidden"` will appear to be empty but you can change `background: #fff;` to any other color you want

```css
td.hidden {
  position: relative;
}

td.hidden:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidden">asd</td>
    <td>zxc</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td class="hidden">zxc</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>zxc</td>
    <td class="hidden">test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```